Newly created EXM templates not showing in the Send Email Campaign Message form's submit action
We are on Sitecore 10.3 PaaS and followed the below steps to create the EXM template

In the Email Experience Manager, click Create.
Select Automated Email Campaign and choose any template.
I added the EXM name, subject, and body and activated the EXM in the Delivery tab.
After activation, I created a form, but when I set the Submit action OOB Send Email Campaign Message and while editing I could not find my newly created EXM in the Message dropdown

We also tried to build the sitecore_master_index but still not showing.


Only active email campaigns are available in the "Select email campaign message" list. Therefore, you have to ensure that your email campaign is active.
Go to EXM -> Draft category section, if you see your email campaign in that list then its activation failed for some reason. Typically, if you left either "Sender details" empty or entered an invalid email address into the "From email" field then this will prevent your email campaign form submission and it won't be activated as a result.
In case your email campaign is shown as activated then try to deactivate it and then activate again on the "Delivery" tab, it might do a trick for you.
